# sidebar appearing under content of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Every time I add a new page either through wordpress and or the new woocommerce pages I have due to installing the woocommerce plugin are all pushing the sidebar to the bottom of the page under the content.

I have no idea why this is happening. Please check attached photo

[image]

This is what the code looks like in my themes sidebar in the CSS

```
/* Sidebar
---------------------------------------- */
#sidebar {
    float: Left;
}

    .widget {
        background: url(images/box-tail.gif) repeat-x 50% 0%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
        border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
        border-top: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    }

        ul.children {
            margin: 0 0 0 20px;
        }

    .widget-indent {
        padding: 0 20px 19px 20px;
    }

.primary_content_wrap .widget {
    padding: 0 19px 19px 19px;
}

.primary_content_wrap h3 {
    padding: 0 0 21px 0;
}

.primary_content_wrap .widget #searchform {
    width: 100%;
}

    .primary_content_wrap .widget #searchform input[type="text"] {
        width: 123px;
    }
```

This is my sidebar.php

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="grid_6 omega">
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar' )) : ?>

        <div id="sidebar-search" class="widget">
            <h3>Search</h3>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?> <!-- outputs the default Wordpress search form-->
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-nav" class="widget menu">
            <h3>Navigation</h3>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Sidebar Menu' )); ?> <!-- editable within the Wordpress backend -->
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-archives" class="widget">
            <h3>Archives</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives( 'type=monthly' ); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-meta" class="widget">
            <h3>Meta</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</aside><!--sidebar-->
```

And then this is how I call the sidebar in each of my pages

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE
Appearance>widgets

[image]

Comment: Check your Appearance -> Widgets and see what's there.

Comment: I have updated my question with an image of Appearance > Widgets and it says in the box that this will appear on the right hand side of pages.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the install? That would help a lot in determining the issue. CSS cascades. There could be something elsewhere in the page causing the issue. The code you posted is not enough to determine the issue or let you know how to solve it.

Comment: please provide a link to the WordPress site; then I can inspect it and figure out where the issue is, it's hard to determine the problem or decide whether to spend the time writing an example of something CSS based that could potentially solve your problem when that may not even be the issue in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked which template the page is currently using?

on the list of "**all pages**",

click on quick edit and from the Template Drop down select a different template for your page?

Comment: This post inspired me to check the pages.. I couldnt find my shop page however I was able to recreate it.. using woocommerce shortcodes.. by doing this it added my sidebar in perfectly!!!!

Thanks a bunch for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your main content width added to the width of the sidebar is less than the width of your page body. That can explain why, even with the "float:left" property your sidebar is going at the bottom of the page.

Also, why not include the whole sidebar code in your php condition :

```
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar' )) : ?>
<aside id="sidebar" class="grid_6 omega">
        <div id="sidebar-search" class="widget">
            <h3>Search</h3>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?> <!-- outputs the default Wordpress search form-->
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-nav" class="widget menu">
            <h3>Navigation</h3>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Sidebar Menu' )); ?> <!-- editable within the Wordpress backend -->
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-archives" class="widget">
            <h3>Archives</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives( 'type=monthly' ); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-meta" class="widget">
            <h3>Meta</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
</aside><!--sidebar-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: okay thanks for the info.. the code above made everything go abit crazy.. however it did manage to get the menu to the right had side its was still unusable though because of what it did to the rest of the site.

Comment: I think im going to try and find the width of the woocommerce cart and make that smaller so the menu fits.. just need to figure that out... soo many pages of code it might be hard to find.

Comment: You can also rewrite the css property. You can find it using Firebug or something like this and override the css property of the block in your own css.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a link to your install?  It is possible the problem lay outside of the code you have provided and might be easier to fix by looking at the live site.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried defining width value in your sidebar and your left content? make your left content float too(if not). For example

```
#sidebar{
    float:right; //much better to use float right if the sidebar will be placed at the right side of the page
    width:100px; //define a smaller temporary value of the width for testing purposes
}

#left_content{
    float:left;
    width:300px;      
}
```

You may try to adjust the css and check the html elements using firebug in your browser.
check this http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most likely something very simple. Your using a grid which makes it very easy to make columns. Your page template would be like so:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

 <div class="container_12">

 <div class="grid_6">
 <--- main content here --->
 </div>

 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

 </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the main content and sidebar have sizes assigned to them that don’t fit next to one another or too much margin or padding, the sidebar will automatically move to the bottom of the screen. this may cause problem